# Capturing Connections in Firefox

Tags: firefox

When Firefox loads a webpage, the bottom-left of the screen briefly displays connection information.  For example:

Waiting for pubads.g.doubleclick.net
Transferring data from insight.adsrvr.org…
Performing a TLS handshake to bttrack.com…

I would like to be able to log these or otherwise intercept them for information purposes.

Comment: Welcome. I don't think you can. You could try using the `INSPECTOR` while the page loads, but...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a web browser not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic]. This question could be on topic on [su].

Answer (score 4):

Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Firefox' Developer Tools. Click on the *Network* ribbon to investigate all requests and responses of the current tab:

[image: Screenshot of Firefox' Developer Tools]

There is also an option to save the results as an HAR file for later:

[image: Im-/Export results as HAR]

Answer (score 0):

That is the method, somehow I didn’t properly explore what was right in front of me.

It is a new day.

From a new Tab in Firefox, from the Menu Bar select:
Tools
Web Developer
Network

At the bottom of your browser window, a split window appears.
Select a website from your bookmarks bar.
A lot of connections fill the table data area
They cram a lot of stuff into this space.

At this point the question becomes, how do we save this table data into a database which affords us more flexibility in viewing and analyzing the information.

But that’s for another day.

Comment: You are basically following up on @dirdi's good answer. You might consider awarding him/her the benefit of a good answer by marking the green check box left of his/her post.

Comment: @Edward Ontko: I extended my answer to cover how to save results.